# How to change color of mat-error (Angular Material)?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material's mat-error inside a form to show validation errors. These are by default displayed in orange. Is it possible to adjust its styling to make them red?

I tried:

```
mat-error{
    color: red !important;
}
```

With no success.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this css.

```
 .mat-input-invalid .mat-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

.mat-input-invalid .mat-input-ripple {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to :root {}

```
:root {
  .brand-theme .mat-error {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-hint
 {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the theme. See [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Or add `::ng-deep` in the css:

`mat-error ::ng-deep{
    color: red;
}`

The `::ng-deep` method is however deprecated, see [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the error color by changing the warn-palette in theming, see https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution also if it helps:

```
:host mat-error {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As of today, these are displayed in red.